# How to run locust in distributed load where I have multiple batch files( differs in item count)

Tags: python-3.x, performance-testing, locust

Current scenario: I have to test load for 5items, 15items, 20items, 25items and 35items for 300 users. When I run my executable batch file(.\abc.bat) it triggers all 5 different batch file(5,15,20,25,35) in parallel.
`.\abc.bat:` override the time, user, host etc which is passed as command line arguments as below :

```
start .\abc.bat 5_item.ini <2hour> <300user> <www.xyx.com host>
start .\abc.bat 15_item.ini <2hour> <300user> <www.xyx.com host>
start .\abc.bat 20_item.ini <2hour> <300user> <www.xyx.com host>
start .\abc.bat 25_item.ini <2hour> <300user> <www.xyx.com host> 
start .\abc.bat 35_item.ini <2hour> <300user> <www.xyx.com host>
```

In the end it results 5 different .html file based on items(which is only variable)

Problem: 300 users can't be handled with 5 different config and with single core of CPU(as locust uses) so it throws **connectionerror(protocolerror('connection aborted.', remotedisconnected('remote end closed connection without response')))**

Now I decided to use master- worker and distributed load and made my X machine as master and Y machine as worker.

The question How to open 5 parallel processes on the worker machine which use all core of CPU of worker machine.

Currently it picks only 5 item run and finishes it but it never picks the rest of the configs and says that address is already in use. Does This means I need 5 machine to run 5 configs?

Question2: If i wanna use same machine as master and worker to use all core of CPU, how i can use it? locust documentation is not clear enough. Remember I don't have one file. I have 5 files which I wanna run in parallel for 5 different kind of items.

I have tried making master my X machine and run the exe bat file after connecting to worker but it always picks one config and run that rest items(15,25,30,35) says address already in use

I tried making my single machine as master and server but it also did not work.
`locust -f my_locustfile.py --worker`

Comment: Hi! Stackoverflow questions need to be narrow in focus (or someone will close it). Either narrow it down to a single question, or ask on Locust’s slack chat instead.

Comment: My only question is: How I can run 5 different batch files which triggers locust scripts with 5 configurations. For higher load with single core, it gives **connectionerror(protocolerror('connection aborted.', remotedisconnected('remote end closed connection without response')))**. Thinking to leverage all the cores. Is it possible with locust to trigger 5 parallel batch files which first sets different values to config and then launch locust file from same config in the last.